# Change css property on loading a page using JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I setup to change a border-color( css property ) of my .gallery( css class) to white, instead of black, when page loads?

I want this property to be the final, no override by index css file or any other css file.

Comment: you can't change your css class via javascript. all you have to do is add different CSS and apply those to your elements conditionally. If you don't want any changes to your element style, either mark  your CSS as !important or try inline styles

Comment: maybe us !important if you are giving it from css, but to be honest what gallery you have there, from where it gets the css? could you not make it custom from there?

Comment: did you use `$('.gallery').attr('style','border-color:black !important')` for example

Comment: You can do that directly in your CSS file: `.gallery {border-color: red}`

Comment: Well, I think there is possibility, because page preloads all css files, and after it, javascript is applied, which means, that we can overrun any css property calling a proper JS code. I was thinking something like   $('.gallery').css('border-color', 'red'); but for some reason, it doesn't work. @KD

Comment: !important attribute in most cases doesn't work, it gets overriden by later css property definition. Tried it already. @DincaAdrian

Comment: your selector $('.gallery').css('border-color', 'red');  will try to get all html elements which has class "galler" and change the border color to red. this is what you need?

Comment: @SamsungBravo I think !important will never be overriden by later css property unless another !important attribute will be declare.

Comment: can you add your html code as well?

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gallery').css('border-color', '#ffffff')
});
```

This sets the style attribute of your node, overriding any properties from your css (unless they are set to `!important`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also change border color by adding class

CSS

```
    .myborder{
      border-color: red;
    }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gallery').addClass('myborder')
});
```